# Which twitter api to go for to be integrated in an iPhone App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, twitter

We have got so many twitter api's now. Which one is suitable if my application for iPhone is supported from iOS 6.X. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "so many Twitter APIs....." There is only one version of the Twitter API you can use right now. Maybe you are talking about libraries/plugins which can be used to communicate with the Twitter API? If so, then I would recommend using Apple's framework called "Social" in conjunction with their "Accounts" framework.

Comment: yeah, there is one called Fabric, OAuth, Rest API's etc., I need to post tweet, search tweets and follow.

Comment: FWIW even though I've answered below, this question is not the kind of format that Stack Overflow encourages, precisely because it is subjective (as you can tell from the responses) http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 4):

Ah I see. You are not stuck on the API, you stuck on the authentication method. Well if you were just going to post tweets, I would have recommended the `SLComposeViewController`. However you want to search tweets and follow users. In order to do this you need to get the user to login with their Twitter account into your app, because all these types of requests need a user account and they need to be authenticated.

Well I would recommend using OAuth 2.0 (or in Twitter's case OAuth 1.0a) as its fairly easy to work with.

However you could also achieve the functionality you want by using Apples built in `Social` and `Accounts` frameworks. They take care of all the authentication for you which makes life a lot easier for you.

The below tutorial link is a little bit old, it does still work and it will give you a superb idea on how to use the users Twitter account via Apple's `Social` framework and it will show you how to load content from Twitter (ie: searching for Tweets).

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-6-and-the-social-framework-twitter-requests--mobile-14840

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

disclaimer - I work at Twitter on our developer products

A good choice would be to use Twitter's own, supported, Twitter Kit inside the [Fabric](http://get.fabric.io) SDK. Fabric works natively on iOS and offers both Objective-C and Swift methods.

Your follow-up comment mentions "OAuth, Rest APIs etc". To clarify, OAuth is required for any call to the Twitter API - Fabric will handle that for you. The REST API is what Fabric uses to interact with Twitter. It will enable you to post Tweets (TweetComposer), and you can use Twitter APIClient to call any of the other REST endpoints (search, create follow relationship etc) for which a convenience method is not provided.

Get Fabric, add Twitter Kit to your project, and then you have all the facilities you need. You can easily display Tweets (or whole timelines) inside your app in a supported way, without having to make multiple calls to the API manually to retrieve user avatar images, any associated media like photos, etc. - all in a few lines of code.

An alternative would be the Social Framework provided in iOS by Apple. Twitter Kit makes use of that to provide features like the TweetComposer. The benefit of using Twitter Kit would be increased portability (the API methods exist on both iOS and Android); the fact that it is supported directly by Twitter; and that if Twitter's Display Guidelines changed, Fabric would be updated to support those.

Comment: ```Social``` framework is much easier to implement though and it takes care of all the OAuth 1.0a nonsense :)